# How to mock propType of Image (React native) in Jest

Tags: react-native, mocking, snapshot, jestjs

I have the following error on a jest test that uses react-native and react-native-router-flux

```
Runtime Error
  - TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/NavBar.js:155:45)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/DefaultRenderer.js:21:13)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-router-flux/index.js:3:22)
```

This is the line that causes the trouble

backButtonImage: Image.propTypes.source,

so I guess that Image.propTypes is not defined correct

How can I fix this?